# How to find the number of possible UNIQUE combinations of numbers in range(n) with special requirements for UNIQUENESS

Tags: combinatorics

You are given a range of n numbers starting at 1.
How do I determine the total number of possible unique combinations/sets if:

- a combination is NOT unique, if it is just presented in a different order. Meaning 1,2,3 is the same as 2,3,1 and 3,2,1 etc. So every set has to be an actual, unique set of numbers, not just the same numbers in a different order
- However you do not have to use all numbers in every set. For instance given the range 1,2,3 just "1" by itself counts as a valid set, so does 1,2.
- Given the range 1,2,3 the would be 6 possible sets 1, 2, 3, 12, 23, 13

Is there a mathematical way to find the number of possible combinations AND is there also a reverse operation for finding n, if the maximum combination of numbers if given?

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in the number of subsets.  However, the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ has eight subsets: $$\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}$$  Did you deliberately omit the empty set and the whole set?

Comment: "Given the range $1,2,3$ there would be $6$ possible sets $1,2,3,12,23,13$"  What about the empty result " "?  What about the full result "$123$"?

Comment: your "combinations" are more commonly called "subsets" and all the possible subsets together forms a collection called a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).  it seems you want to ignore some special cases, so season to taste.